# Draw line with scrollable canvas window

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am new one for canvas.I want to know how to draw a line with scrollable canvas window.my expectation is canvas window fit the screen and if line went to out side of the view port then the canvas window is scrollable until to view the end of the line.i try this code.any idea for this problem.Thank you.
`<html>`
`<head>`
`<head>`
`<body>`
`<canvas id="myCanvas"  style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;float: left;" > Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>`
`<script>`
`function draw() {`
`var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");`
`var ctx = c.getContext("2d");`
  `ctx.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;`
  `ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;`
`ctx.beginPath();`
`ctx.moveTo(100,100);`
`ctx.lineTo(1500,1000);`
`ctx.stroke();`
`}`
`draw();`
`</script>`
`</body>`
`</html>`

Answer (score 1):

You can have the browser add scrollbar(s) by wrapping a taller canvas inside a shorter div and setting the shorter div's `overflow:scroll`.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100,100);
ctx.lineTo(200,1000);
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#viewport{width:320px;height:150px;border:1px solid blue;overflow:scroll;}
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<div id=viewport>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=1500></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: here canvas width,height is our value.If `lineTo(200,2000);` can't view full line.I need canvas view port fit the screen and if line go to out of the screen then view port is scrollable.

Comment: Sure. You can do that. I just wanted my demo to fit in the Stackoverflow snippet window ;-)

Comment: I got idea from your answer.but i'm not copy that.my specification is canvas window is can scroll able depend on length of the line.anyway sorry and thanks for your answer and comments.